# Select range in interactive shiny plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, interactive

I am trying to create an interactive visualisation of data in shiny. The visualisation shows the distribution (or histogramm) of parts of a series. For example, the following code creates a series and two selections (two is fixed) of parts of the series, which is then displayed using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:1000,
                  y = cumsum(rnorm(1000, mean = 0.1)))
sel1 <- 200:400 # selection 1
sel2 <- 700:900 # Selection 2

# create a plot of the series
ggplot() + geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = sel1[1], xmax = sel1[length(sel1)], 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.5, fill = "red") + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = sel2[1], xmax = sel2[length(sel2)], 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.5, fill = "blue")

# Histogramm preparation
# create another df that contains the selection of the two selections
pdat <- rbind(data.frame(y = dat[dat$x %in% sel1, 2],
                         sel = 1),
              data.frame(y = dat[dat$x %in% sel2, 2],
                         sel = 2))

# plot the histograms
ggplot(pdat, aes(x = y, fill = as.factor(sel))) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, position = "dodge")
```

which creates: 
[image: Shaded Regions]
[image: Histograms]

Now I want the user to be able to move the areas (preferably by dragging the shaded areas in plot 1 around!) using shiny.

I played around with the (new) interactive options of shiny (more info [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/), look for section "Interactive plots"). I think I can remember that there is an option to specify an area, which the user is able to drag around, but I can't find it anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into the `D3` library?

Comment: I think you should look into those JS libraries yourself (as suggested) and go through tutorials where you can practice. The common ones are `rCharts`, `HighCharts`, `D3` as your objective isn't that straight forward

Comment: As much as I like `rCharts`, there is an option using `ggplot2` and shiny's interactive ability. I think I found an example in this shiny app: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-advanced.html
If you use the `BRUSH` direction = "x", you get an area that can be used to specify inputs for a second graph! 
No need for JS, yet...

Comment: does the data frame has to be an index object or is a timeseries?

Comment: I prefer data.frame or data.table and try to avoid `xts`-objects wherever possible!

Comment: I will post something now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution that is able to use interactive `ggplot`'s in a `shiny` environment. The code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ifna <- function(x, elseval = NA) ifelse(is.na(x) || is.null(x), elseval, x)

# two plots: as described in the question
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("plotui"),
  plotOutput("plot2")
)

server = function(input, output) {
  set.seed(123)
  dat <- data.frame(x = 1:1000,
                    val = cumsum(rnorm(1000, mean = 0.1)))
  base <- 200:400 # Base Selection

  # reactive expressions to get the values from the brushed area
  selmin <- reactive(round(ifna(input$plot_brush$xmin, elseval = 700), 0))
  selmax <- reactive(round(ifna(input$plot_brush$xmax, elseval = 900), 0))

  # include the brush option: direction = "x" says that y values are fixed (min and max)
  output$plotui <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("plot", height = 300, 
               brush = brushOpts(id = "plot_brush", direction = "x",
                                 fill = "blue", opacity = 0.5)
    )
  })

  # render the first plot including brush
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = val)) +
      geom_rect(aes(xmin = base[1], xmax = base[length(base)], 
                    ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.5, fill = "red") + 
      geom_rect(aes(xmin = 700, xmax = 900, 
                    ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.1, fill = "blue") +
      ylab("Value") + xlab("t")
  })

  # render the second plot reactive to the brushed area
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

    # prepare the data
    pdat <- rbind(data.frame(y = dat[dat$x %in% base, "val"],
                             type = "Base"),
                  data.frame(y = dat[dat$x %in% selmin():selmax(), "val"],
                             type = "Selection"))

    ggplot(pdat, aes(x = y, fill = type)) + 
      geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, position = "dodge") + 
      scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue")) + 
      theme(legend.position = "bottom") + ylab("Frequency") + xlab("Value")
  })
}

# run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Which gives something like this (the dark-blue box is interactive, as in you can push it around and the lower graph updates!

[Picture of Shiny App](http://puu.sh/l0KjF/6d0a514f12.png)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments do look into [rCharts](http://rcharts.io/) and [dygraphs](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/shiny.html), below is the example taken from tutorials with some modifications. Please note that the `dygraphs` require a timeseries object to plot, refer to official [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dygraphs/dygraphs.pdf) for more information. The summary statistics can be performed by a package of your choice. Also note that the shaded regions are user specified...

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
library(rCharts)

index <- as.Date(c(seq(Sys.time(), length.out = 1000, by = "days")))
dat <- data.frame(x = index,y = cumsum(rnorm(1000, mean = 0.1)))
dat <- xts(dat[,-1], order.by=dat[,1])

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shaded Regions using dygraphs and rCharts by Pork Chop"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("range_one", "Range One:",min = 100, max = 1000, value = c(200,300)),
      sliderInput("range_two", "Range Two:",min = 100, max = 1000, value = c(500,600)),width=3),
    mainPanel(
      column(12,dygraphOutput("dygraph")),
      column(12,showOutput("summary", "Highcharts"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(dat, main = "Sample Data") %>% 
      dyShading(from = index[input$range_one[1]], to = index[input$range_one[2]], color = "#FFE6E6") %>%
      dyShading(from = index[input$range_two[1]], to = index[input$range_two[2]], color = "#CCEBD6")
  })

  output$summary <- renderChart2({

    Selection1 <- dat[input$range_one[1]:input$range_one[2]]
    Selection2 <- dat[input$range_two[1]:input$range_two[2]]    
    subset_data <- data.frame(merge(Selection1,Selection2))
    a <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
    a$chart(type = "column")
    a$title(text = "Summary Stats")
    a$yAxis(title = list(text = "Count"))
    a$data(subset_data)
    a$exporting(enabled=T)
    a$set(width = 1200,height = "100%",slider = TRUE)
    return(a)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is also an interesting approach that looks visually attractive!
However, I prefer my solution as it allows for a more user-friendly interaction. Your appraoch could be realised using `ggplot` if I am not mistaken. Nonetheless, thank you for the answer!